# Fade in image after loading with load()

Tags: jquery, image, fadein

I'm trying to fade in an image after loading the image (and some html surrounding it) with jQuery load();. I understand I should use the callback on load(); but I don't know how to target/chain the image within the callback. Simplified code below:

jQuery

```
$(".load-post").click(function(){
    var post_link = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#image-container").load(post_link,function(l){
        $(this).load(function(e){
            $(this).fadeIn(1000); //?
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

Container

```
<div id="image-container"></div>
```

Loaded content

```
<figure><img src=/images/image.jpg"></figure>
```

How to I 'approach' the `<img>` after loading it?

Comment: did you mean: <figure><img src="/images/image.jpg"></figure>

Comment: Yes, fixed by Jason P.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from the problem is that you want to Load an Image after some piece of content has been loaded by Ajax.

```
$(".load-post").click(function(){
        var post_link = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#image-container").load(post_link,function(l){
        //This function is triggered after your content has loaded successfully inside your #image_container.
        //Suppose you have an image <img id="after_fadein" src="loadme.png" />
        //Now simply fade In the image using DOM manipulation.
        $('#after_fadein').fadeIn(1000);
            });
        });
    });`
```